# Getting "Invald property value" on animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

The following code results in an "invalid property value" on the animation properties and I'm not sure why.

**edit, complete code**

```
.spinner {
  animation: rotator 1.4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotator {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(270deg); }
}

.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 187;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  animation:
    dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite, 
    colors 5.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes colors {
    0% { stroke: #4285F4; }
    25% { stroke: #DE3E35; }
    50% { stroke: #F7C223; }
    75% { stroke: #1B9A59; }
  100% { stroke: #4285F4; }
}

@keyframes dash {
 0% { stroke-dashoffset: 187; }
 50% {
   stroke-dashoffset: 46.75;
   transform:rotate(135deg);
 }
 100% {
   stroke-dashoffset: 187;
   transform:rotate(450deg);
 }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a spinner taken from this example:
http://codepen.io/mrrocks/pen/EiplA

Comment: Your first 4 lines are syntactically invalid.

Comment: how should they be corrected?  separate them out individually without using the base animation (so animation-delay, animation-duration, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Chrome/Safari you'll have to add the -webkit-animation for `.spinner` like so:

```
-webkit-animation: rotator 1.4s infinite linear;
```

and you'll have to do the same for `.path`:

```
-webkit-animation: dash 1.4s ease-in-out infinite, colors 5.6s ease-in-out infinite;
```

SASS will generate `animation` and `-webkit-animation` both, but you'll have to do them manually in CSS.

Comment: yeah I added those.  I'll post the whole code.  One difference is that I'm using basic CSS instead of SASS

Comment: @StevenHarlow Webkit browsers require prefixed animation tags. Updated the answer with what is presumably your problem.

Comment: That solved the invalid property value issue so I'm marking this as accepted :)  I still do not see my spinner unfortunately :(

Comment: @StevenHarlow Can you post a fiddle with your current code?